# Establecer unidades de eje x e y de manera independiente matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

He programado una gráfica tal que la escala de valores tanto en el eje X como en el eje Y es muy distinta, razón por la cual no utilizo **‘plt.axis(‘equal’)’**, pero sí requiero visualizar de mejor manera los valores de mi eje X, ya que actualmente no se ven por el tema de las escalas, qué método se podría aplicar para éste caso, gracias.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

drift = np.array([0,0.209,0.238,0.145])

# Elaborar gráfico --------------------------------------------------------

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Líneas maestras cada 1m, líneas menores cada 0.25m.
major_ticks = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
minor_ticks = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)

ax.set_xticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks, minor=True)

# Añado el correspondiente grid
ax.grid(which='both')
# Configuro los grosores de línea de los grids:
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)

plt.plot(drift, np.arange(4))
```

Aquí dejo una gráfica realizada en excel que explica mejor lo que busco hacer, si se fijan las unidades del eje X son muy distintas a las del eje Y, es exactamente así como busco visualizarlas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que le estás asignando las mismas marcas mayores a ambos ejes, por lo que los ticks en <kbd>X</kbd> van de 1 en 1 y deberían de ir de 0.1 en 0.1 Debes crear una marcas adecuadas a tu eje  <kbd>X</kbd>:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


drift = np.array([-0, 0.209, 0.238, 0.145])

# Elaborar gráfico --------------------------------------------------------

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Líneas maestras cada 1m, líneas menores cada 0.25m.

x_max = np.ceil(np.max(drift) * 10) / 10
x_min = np.floor(np.min(drift) * 10) / 10

major_ticks_x = np.arange(x_min, x_max + 0.1, 0.1)
minor_ticks_x = np.arange(x_min, x_max + 0.1, 0.01)
major_ticks_y = np.arange(0, 10, 1)
minor_ticks_y = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)

ax.set_xticks(major_ticks_x)
ax.set_xticks(minor_ticks_x, minor=True)
ax.set_yticks(major_ticks_y)
ax.set_yticks(minor_ticks_y, minor=True)

ax.set_xlim(xmax=x_max, xmin=np.min(drift))

# Añado el correspondiente grid
ax.grid(which='both')
# Configuro los grosores de línea de los grids:
ax.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.2)
ax.grid(which='major', alpha=0.5)

plt.plot(drift, np.arange(4))  
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Efectivamente, gracias @FJSevilla.